# Class diagram for C# Library and classes

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, uml

I am a java developer.I am using java's class diagram to study it.I want to found class diagram (UML) from C# to study about its libraries and methods. Can you introduce me any link to download or found it.

Sincerely you M.Bagheri

Answer (score 2):

In VS2010 you could right-click on C# project -> View class diagram.